# Values on y-axis disappear after using scale_y

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2

I've got such a problem. When I use such a code:

```
  dat3 <- data.frame(
  oprocentowanie <- factor(proc),
  składka <- factor(wektor_skladek))
dat3

png(filename = "/home/nilcorc/Documents/Licencjat/Rubezpieczenie/plots/analiza_oprocentowania_skladka",
    width = 600, height = 400)
ggplot(data=dat3, aes(oprocentowanie, składka)) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", width=0.5, color="#6666FF",stat="identity",fill="#6666FF")+
  labs(title="Wrażliwość składki na stopę %")
dev.off()
```

I get a plot with float values on Y-axis, but when I add

```
scale_y_discrete(breaks=c(0,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000)
```

all values on Y-axis disappear and I just get a plot where I don't know how big are the bars. Could you help me?

I would like to get values on Y-axis going from 0 to 9000 by 1000.

Data frame:

```
 oprocentowanie....factor.proc. skladki....factor.floor.wektor_skladek..
1                             0%                                     8216
2                           0.5%                                     7053
3                             1%                                     6053
4                           1.5%                                     5195
5                             2%                                     4458
6                           2.5%                                     3826
7                             3%                                     3286
8                           3.5%                                     2825
9                             4%                                     2431
```

The plot without scale:
[image: Without numbers]

The plot with scale:
[image: With numbers]

And the dput:

```
structure(list(oprocentowanie....factor.proc. = structure(1:9, .Label = c("0%", 
"0.5%", "1%", "1.5%", "2%", "2.5%", "3%", "3.5%", "4%"), class = "factor"), 
    skladki....factor..wektor_skladek.. = structure(c(9L, 8L, 
    7L, 6L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 2L, 1L), .Label = c("2431.59459253388", 
    "2825.48111629658", "3286.93674975244", "3826.96130538247", 
    "4458.17016548586", "5195.00332453903", "6053.96171257516", 
    "7053.8763920252", "8216.21779413142"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("oprocentowanie....factor.proc.", 
"skladki....factor..wektor_skladek.."), row.names = c(NA, -9L
), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Can you please post a [MWE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? Without knowing what your data look like, or being able to recreate the error, it is nearly impossible to help. At the very least, can you post the versions both with and without values on the y axis? My first guess is that your bars are not 1000 units tall.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try making the `składka` column numeric instead of a factor. Notice how the steps between each bar are all the same size, even though the labels diverge by more than that? (e.g. 2431 to 2825 is the same distance as 7053 to 8216.) That is because each is just the next label in the levels of your factor. So, if you add `scale_y_discrete(breaks=1:9)` you will (correctly) get the labels 1 through 9.

This should work:

```
ggplot(data=dat3, aes(oprocentowanie, as.numeric(as.character(składka)))) +
  geom_bar(position="dodge", width=0.5, color="#6666FF",stat="identity",fill="#6666FF")+
  labs(title="Wrażliwość składki na stopę %") +
  scale_y_continuous(breaks=c(0,1000,2000,3000,4000,5000,6000,7000,8000,9000)
```

It would help more if you could post code that we can run directly, e.g., with the output of `dput(dat3)`

(Edited to use `scale_y_continuous` instead of `scale_y_discrete`)

Comment: Unfortunately it still gives the same result.

Comment: My guess is that if you plot without the scale, my first version would give you 1:9. I forgot the `as.character` part necessary in converting back to numeric from character (and was not able to check it). It would probably be best to not make it a factor in the first place.  Try with the addition.

Comment: It's still the same with the addition. Maybe there's another way to change the scale? I looked for some help in the internet, but if I add limits or something, the axis also disappears.

Comment: The only difference now is that the very left bar goes to the same top of the scale (but there's still no value).

Comment: Can you post the results of `dput(dat3)` in your question so that I can actually try running it to see what is happening?